# GetFolder method does not return Folder object (it returns a string instead)

Tags: excel, vba, filesystemobject

I'm working on a set of codes that require GetFolder method to return a Folder object. I've written and debugged the following set of codes with the Microsoft Scripting Runtime activated:

```
Sub test()

Dim fso As FileSystemObject, fld As folder, fl As file

Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set fld = fso.GetFolder("D:\test\")

MsgBox VarType(fso)
MsgBox VarType(fso.GetFolder("D:\test\"))

End Sub
```

However, I get an error code 13 for type mismatch. I would like to assign the Folder object (same as expected behavior in documentation) to the fld variable but it isn't working as expected in the documentation.

As I was troubleshooting this, I've tried running the following set of codes:

```
Sub test()

Dim fso As FileSystemObject, fld As folder, fl As file

Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

MsgBox VarType(fso)
MsgBox VarType(fso.GetFolder("D:\test\"))

End Sub
```

The first MsgBox provided an output of 9, indicating that it is an Object variable. However, the second MsgBox provided an output of 8, indicating that it is a String variable. I've also checked against the documentation and other online sources but no other users have encountered this issue.

Edit: Also attempted additional codes as follows:

```
    Option Explicit
    Sub test()

    Dim fso As FileSystemObject, fld As folder, fl As file

    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

    MsgBox TypeName(fso.GetFolder("D:\"))
    MsgBox VarType(fso)
    MsgBox VarType(fso.GetFolder("D:\"))
    MsgBox fso.FolderExists("D:\")
    Set fld = fso.GetFolder("D:\")

    End Sub
```

MsgBox order returned "Folder", "9", "8", True in sequence before having an error at Set fld = fso.GetFolder("D:").

Comment: It would help if you also shared the code that gave you the error code 13

Comment: It is a Folder object - if you run `MsgBox TypeName(fso.GetFolder("D:\test\"))` or `MsgBox TypeName(fld)` you get `Folder`.

Comment: The answer from @hennep explains why you get type string in your 2nd message box. This doesn't explain the type mismatch, you need to show the code that raises this error.

Comment: @CHill60 The first code block gave an error code 13 at Set fld = fso.GetFolder("D:\test\")

Comment: @OlleSjögren Yes, it provided me with the "Folder" message box when I used TypeName. I inserted the codes you provided, and Set fld = fso.GetFolder("D:\test\") after that. Error 13 continues to appear after the MsgBox displaying "Folder". 

|@FunThomas Type mismatch appears when running Set fld = fso.GetFolder("D:\test\")

Comment: Are you sure the code that fails is exactly the same as in your question or could there be a typo? Your code works for me in Excel 2016 without error. Try adding `Option Explicit` at the top of the code module and compiling to see if there are any hidden errors with mismatching variable names or something.

Comment: @OlleSjögren I've added Option Explicit as you have recommended and revised the codes a little as below:
``
Option Explicit
Sub test()

Dim fso As FileSystemObject, fld As folder, fl As file

Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

MsgBox TypeName(fso.GetFolder("D:\"))
MsgBox VarType(fso)
MsgBox VarType(fso.GetFolder("D:\"))
MsgBox fso.FolderExists("D:\")
Set fld = fso.GetFolder("D:\")

End Sub
``
The series of message boxes produce output of "Folder", "9", "8" and True. However, the cursor stops at Set fld = fso.GetFolder("D:\")

Comment: Please add the updated code to your question, much easier to read that way! :) That said, the new code also works for me, I get the same results in the message boxes as you, but no error on the last line, and `fld` is a valid Folder object.

Comment: Are you perhaps using 32-bit Office on a 64-bit machine? Thinking that the `CreateObject` is going for the 64-bit version of sscrun.dll whereas the `Dim` is defining a 32-bit object.
Try using `Dim fso As Object, fld As Object` OR use early binding e.g. `Set fso = New FileSystemObject`

Comment: @OlleSjögren Sure, will add the new codes into the question. Thanks for the recommendation.

Comment: @CHill60 Checked on the Excel version and it's 64-bit.

Comment: @AlexTee - but did you try either of the code options I suggested?

Comment: @CHill60 Dim fso as Object, fld as Object works normally without error. I'll post the revised solution. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

After multiple attempts to resolve it, the set of codes that do not lead to an error are as follows:

```
    Sub test()

    Dim fso As Object, fld As Object, fl As Object

    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

    MsgBox TypeName(fso.GetFolder("D:\"))
    MsgBox VarType(fso)
    MsgBox VarType(fso.GetFolder("D:\"))
    MsgBox fso.FolderExists("D:\")
    Set fld = fso.GetFolder("D:\")

    End Sub
```

Credit for actively looking for a solution: @OlleSjögren @CHill60

Answer (score 0):

I think that VarType returns 8 because the default property of the folder object is a string

```
Sub test()
    Dim fso As FileSystemObject, fld As folder, fl As file, f As Object
    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    MsgBox "object f=" & VarType(f)
    Set f = fso.GetFolder("C:\temp\")
    MsgBox "object f=" & VarType(f)
    MsgBox f.DateCreated ' <<< it behaves as an object
    MsgBox "default property:" & f
End Sub
```

Comment: Correct.  The OP could have used a Watch on their `fld` variable to confirm this as well

Comment: Watch on fld variable was used. Type was Folder during the debugging process.

Answer (score 0):

**TLDR:** Change the declaration of your Folder variable from Folder to Scripting.Folder

So, I got this annoying problem only in some workbooks.

Initially, my workaround was to change declaring  my Folder variable from Folder to Object.
Then I noticed that I did not get the problem if I changed declaring  my Folder variable from Folder to Scripting.Folder

```
Sub MicrosoftScriptingRuntimeObjectGetFolder() '  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77220774/getfolder-method-does-not-return-folder-object-it-returns-a-string-instead
' Early Binding
Dim FSO As Scripting.FileSystemObject: Set FSO = New Scripting.FileSystemObject          '               https://i.postimg.cc/d1GHPGxJ/Microsoft-Scripting-Runtime-Library.jpg

Dim ObjFolder As Folder
Dim ObjFolderObject As Object
Dim ObjScriptFolder As Scripting.Folder

Debug.Print TypeName(FSO.GetFolder(ThisWorkbook.Path & Application.PathSeparator)) ' This always gives me  Folder
Debug.Print VarType(FSO.GetFolder(ThisWorkbook.Path & Application.PathSeparator)) ' This always gives me  8  for  String  type, whether I then get the type mismatch problem at  FSO.GetFolder(   or not.
 
 Set ObjFolderObject = FSO.GetFolder(ThisWorkbook.Path & Application.PathSeparator) ' This always works
 Set ObjScriptFolder = FSO.GetFolder(ThisWorkbook.Path & Application.PathSeparator) ' This always works
 Set ObjFolder = FSO.GetFolder(ThisWorkbook.Path & Application.PathSeparator)       ' This gives the type mismatch error in some workbooks only. Mess about with your checked Library referrences and you might get rid of the problem
End Sub
```

Furthermore: If I left my Folder variable declared as Folder, I was able to get rid of the problem by unchecking a reference I had to Microsoft Shell Controls And Automation Library. Rechecking that reference  to Microsoft Shell Controls And Automation Library  does not always bring the problem.
Maybe someone smarter can explain that better, or maybe I can later when I get the problem more often and then investigate further how the problem goes away and comes back, but my  explanation for now is that if you use just Folder, then depending on other things, it may declare it as a  Microsoft Scripting Runtime Library Folder if you are lucky, and if you are unlucky it might declare if to some other Folder object

Alan